# Toggle Button inside function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to control the enable/disable states of a particular button. The behavior should be:

1.) If the player doesn't have enough "things" the button remains disabled;

2.) If the player has enough "things" the button should be enabled.

I've seen some pretty complex approaches to this problem but I'm looking for something simple to understand.

A quick research revealed the `document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;` property. I tried to add a unique id to the button in the index.html file and use an if/else statement inside the buyGen() function to switch the button states, but to no avail.

Is my way of thinking correct or is there a simpler way? I'll include the "clean" code to show you what I've got, since my additions didn't work out.

**main.js**

```
var things = 0;
var gen1 = 0;


function thingClick(number) {
    things = things + number;
    document.getElementById("things").innerHTML = things;
}

function buyGen1() {
    var gen1Cost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, gen1));
    if(things >= gen1Cost) {
        gen1 = gen1 + 1;
        things = things - gen1Cost;
        document.getElementById('gen1').innerHTML = gen1;
        document.getElementById('things').innerHTML = things;
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1, gen1));
    document.getElementById('gen1Cost').innerHTML = nextCost;
}

window.setInterval(function(){

    thingClick(gen1);

}, 1000);
```

**index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
        Things: <span id="things">0</span><br><br>
        <button onClick="thingClick(1)">Get Things</button><br><br>
        <button onClick="buyGen1()">Buy Generator Lvl. 1</button><br><br>
        Generators Lvl. 1: <span id="gen1">0</span> | Cost: <span id="gen1Cost">10</span>

     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `things` will always be `0`, so the if-statement will never be true. I'm also not seeing where `disabled` is being used.

Comment: If you're not modifying html, don't use `innerHTML`, use `textContent` instead.

Comment: Can you show where disabled is used?